# XlFileFormat for excel 2010 file

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I want to create a excel 2010 file from C#
so what will be the XlFileFormat Enumeration for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` for a .xlsx macro free workbook.
- `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` for a .xlsm macro enabled workbook.

The key piece of knowledge is that the new Office 2007 file formats are called [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).